# Casting Event Sender to Underlying DataTemplate Type

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, treeview, datatemplate

I have a wpf application that displays a 'Node' as such:

```
<TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="treeView1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Margin="6,6,6,35">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Node}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsThreeState="{Binding HasChildren}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding Text}" Click="RefreshTree" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

I would like to do the following:

```
private void RefreshTree(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Node leaf = sender as Node;

    // Do stuff with leaf
}
```

This fails to cast, as object is of type Controls.CheckBox. Is there a way to get the sender of the event as my underlying template type (Node)?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Node will be available as the DataContext, like so:

```
var checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
var node = checkBox.DataContext as Node;
```

That's what the Bindings in your XAML are using also.